# Anyone know a good standard reference for Lie group and Lie algebra facts?

Tags: reference-request, lie-groups, lie-algebras

I'm writing something and I need to refer to a mathematical fact; unfortunately I got it from Wikipedia, which does not source the specific piece of info! It relates to a choice of simple roots for $\mathfrak{su}(N)$ being the $N-1$ vectors given by $(1,-1,0,0,...,0)^T$, $(0,1,-1,0,...,0)^T$, ..., $(0,0,...,1,-1)^T$ (all of dimension $N$).

My question is: is there a standard text people refer to in these circumstances? Can anyone give me a go-to book? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Lie groups and Lie algebras, by N. Bourbaki.

Comment: Thanks! Can I just confirm something with you - is the above fact definitely in that text?

Comment: If you can give a page number too that would be amazing, but it's not essential.

Answer (score 0):

One of many references is the book [Lie Groups Beyond an Introduction](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0817642595), by Anthony W. Knapp. Appendix $C$ gives data for simple Lie algebras (page 508 ff).